# Obtener solo Mes/Año de una fecha (el Día no) C#

Tags: c#, android, date, xamarin, datetime

Necesito quitarle el día y las horas a unas fechas en Xamarin C# para teniendo esto:

```
15/10/2020 10:00:00:00
```

Obtener esto:

```
Octubre del 2020
```

Intente con:

```
string FechaFormateada = fecha.ToString("MMMM") + " del " + fecha.ToString("yyyy")
```

Pero obtengo los meses en ingles.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes establecer un `CultureInfo` en español y pasarlo como parámetro al `ToString()`

Ejemplo:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
    
DateTime fecha = DateTime.Now;
    
string FechaFormateada = fecha.ToString("MMMM",ci) + " del " + fecha.ToString("yyyy");
```

Puedes agregarle este código luego si es extrictamente necesario que el mes empiece en mayúscula.

```
FechaFormateada = char.ToUpper(FechaFormateada[0]) + FechaFormateada.Substring(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener siempre los meses en español define un `CultureInfo` en este caso puedes usar `"es-ES"`:

```
string FechaFormateada = fecha.ToString("MMMM", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES")) + " del " + fecha.ToString("yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES"));
```

de esta forma siempre obtendrás el més en idioma español:

```
Octubre del 2020
```